# import QCustomPlot2 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.7, qcustomplot

I am trying to get QCustomPlot2 working on Ppython 3.7 Anaconda installation Windows 10 x64

I tried installing via `pip` and `easy_install` from building qcustomplot2 via qt cmd and moved the `.pyd` file into several locations. I updated pyqt from conda which then broke the install. However even when qcustomplot2 was installed, and not giving the dll error I was getting the stack buffer overflow error when calling it from the example.

I am using the PyCharm IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not really an answer but a workaround:

I use `PyQt5` instead of `PySide2` and **you have to import it prior to `QCustomPlot2`**

**Doesn't work:**

```
>>> import QCustomPlot2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QCustomPlot2
```

**Works:**

```
>>> import PyQt5
>>> import QCustomPlot2
```